# PHP fopen "failed to open stream: resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: linux, apache, php

EDIT: Austin below in the comments resolved my issue. How do I close the question since that is the answer?

I have the following simple code to open/write to a query file on my server. I've checked permissions and even set +rw for all users on the query file, yet I still get the error

> failed to open stream: resource temporarily unavailable

in my apache error log.

I'm not really sure what I can do to alleviate this issue, thoughts?

```
<?php 
// filepaths
$queryFile = '../query/query.txt';

// get query
$query = $_GET['searchBox'];

// open and write query to query file
$fh = fopen($queryFile, 'X') or die("Can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $query);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Check out: [file_put_contents()](http://us.php.net/file_put_contents)

Comment: Are you sure the current working directory is what you think it is? What happens if you prepend `dirname(__FILE__)` to `$queryFile`?

Comment: Does the file already exist? According to PHP documentation, the `fopen()` mode `x` returns false and generates a warning if the file already exists. - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: The file does exist, that is surely the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @EthanWillis: Ask Austin to add this as an answer. You could also answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

It could only be one of a few things:

- The PHP process is out of memory, file handles, or similar
- The PHP environment's own limitations are exceeded somehow
- The file itself has some limitation, such as a SELinux (Security Enhanced Linux) restriction.

To determine which it is, try opening the file outside PHP.  Temporarily alter the script to open a different file.  Look at what else the script does to validate whether it could possibly be running out of file handles, etc.

Answer (score 2):

What does `is_file($queryFile)` and `is_writable($queryFile)` reveal? Maybe you are not in the correct working directory?

Answer (score -1):

The parameter `'X'` should be lowercase.

Comment: It's not an answer, it should be a comment.